# flash cs4 textfield

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

im rendering html in a dynamic textfield.. is it possible to have scrollbars for my content that extends beyond the view.

i tried googling and came up with nothing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible!

You need to set a container and a mask with a set height then add scrollbars to scroll your TextField.

Check this Lee Brimelow tutorial for more details
http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=71

Comment: I haven't used Flex in quite some time but if you were looking for something that simple, Flex would be my first guess since it comes with a library of components, but in AS3 , you'd have to code this yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean with "that extends beyond the view", but you could use a component for that? Just open the 'components window', and drag a scrollbar on the textfield.